# Convert an int column to a varchar in FrontBase SQL?

Tags: sql, casting, integer, varchar, frontbase

How do I convert an int column to a varchar in **FrontBase SQL**? I need to concatenate a **varchar** and an **int** field, and I cannot just concatenate them because both arguments need to be a varchar.

I wanted to tag this "Frontbase" but I don't have permission due to reputation < 1500.

Server and database version is 4.2.7

The query looks like this:

```
select (TVERKOPEN.CPREFIX || CAST(TVERKOPEN.CNUMMER AS VARCHAR)) as PurchaseOrder
from TVERKOPEN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
CAST(field AS VARCHAR(30))
```

Comment: I get this error: Exception condition 239. Data exception - string data, right truncation.

Comment: I think I found it... I have to specify VARCHAR(30) or some other length. If you update your answer I can approve it (because it was mostly right).

Comment: However I found `SQL-92` (which is base for FrontBase) documentation about casting and allowed operations: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.2/ref/rrefsqlj33562.html ;-)